# Why is '0' put in this the putchar function when I want a number printed

Tags: c, unix, ascii, putchar

I am trying to print numbers using the putchar() function. Here's my code below:

```
int main(void)
{

    int x = 0;

    for (; x <= 9; x++)
    {
      putchar(x + '0');
    }
    }
    _putchar('\n');
}
```

If run without the " + '0'", no result is visible on the shell.

Does this have to do with the ASCII? Who can help explain what's going on behind the scene?

Thanks

Comment: Your posted code does not compile. It is missing all `#include` directives and the `{` an `}` are mismatched. Also, what is `_putchar`? You seem to be calling a platform-specific function. Did you mean `putchar`?

Comment: Oh, apologies. "_putchar()" was a modified function that I had put in another header "main.h".

That was included at the beginning of the code " #include "main.h"

Answer (score 5):

`putchar` expects a character code as its input. The character codes for digits from `0` to `9` may vary in different encodings, but they <s>almost</s> always come sequentially (including in ASCII). This means that if you have the digit `n` and want to get the corresponding character, the simplest way to acheive that is to add the character code of `'0'` to it. (Character codes in C are represented by the `char` type, and treated like regular numbers, so addition is perfectly valid for them. However, it's important to realize that, in <s>most</s> all C-compatible encodings, `'0'`'s character code is not 0. In ASCII in particular, it's 48. But it's more comprehensible and universal to write `'0'` than `48`)

Note that it, obviously, only works for singe digits, though.

EDIT: Fixed according to the comments

Comment: The character codes for digits 0 to 9 are guaranteed to be sequential in the C specification. (That is not true for the letters a-z, A-Z.)

Comment: Re: *"almost always come sequentially"* -  the C standard requires that `'0`' .. `'9'` be sequential in both the source and execution character set. For example, [C11 §5.2.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1).

Comment: Also, `'0'` cannot be zero in any encoding; zero is reserved for the null terminator.